# Is there visa control on intra-Schengen flights?

Tags: visas

I live in Germany right now and I want to go to Greece. I am a non-EU citizen. Do they check visas?

Comment: It seems to depend on the airline.  Governments can do sporadic checks, but some airlines make a point of checking as a matter of course.

Comment: From what I understand, if you have a visa to be in Germany, you should be fine to travel to other Shengen countries, although you may have a time limit on how long you would be allowed to be there.

Comment: Do you have a visa for staying in Germany? And is it valid or expired?

Answer (score 3):

There are two sides to this, the airline and the authorities.

On the airline side AIUI Ryanair demand a "travel document check" but most other airlines do not. It is not clear how in depth this check is.

On the immigation authorities side there are not supposed to be long term systematic checks but AIUI there can be random checks, intelligence driven checks and temporary systematic checks.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to actual border control, none is performed going from Germany to Greece.

Coming back, however, [Germany currently are performing checks on passengers arriving from Greece](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control_en). I called the *Bundespolizei* in Munich, who said that flights **arriving from** Greece park in the non-Schengen sector of the airport.

In this case, make sure to tell the police you're arriving from Greece so as not to get a second entry stamp (as you never left Schengen to begin with)

Comment: It can't be that passengers arriving from Greece in Munich are simply let into the non-schengen area of the terminals. If they are not segregated, you could fly Greece - MUC, transfer to a flight to a non-schengen destination and leave the Schengen area without exit checks. I haven't been flying to Greece to Munich lately, but according to this forum post (in German), passengers from Greece are kept completely segregated: http://www.vielfliegertreff.de/airlines-fliegen/114059-wiedereinfuehrung-von-passkontrollen-bei-fluegen-von-griechenland-nach-deutschland.html#post2465783

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Read the post. Strange given what the police told me.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Noticed this "In LYS ist Ankunft und Abflug auch von Flügen aus Schengen-Ländern (Erfahrung mit DE, AT) de facto im Non Schengen-Bereich, mit Passkontrollen bei Ein- und Ausreise, und in NCE ist der SN-Flug aus Brüssel im Non-Schengen-Bereich. Was natürlich völlig absurd ist, wer dann BRU-ZRH/MUC/FRA/VIE-NCE fliegt, kommt ohne Kontrollen im Schengen-Bereich an. Allerdings auch dort teilweise Stichproben am Ausgang...." In short, just another reason why I find the whole concept of Schengen to be BS.

Comment: The statement you are quoting from the Bundespolizei, makes at it stands, unfortunately not much sense at all. In Munich, the *terminals* are separated in "Schengen" and "Non-Schengen" areas, but not the parking positions. It is not relevant where the planes are parking, as from any parking position, the disembarking passengers can be led to the right section of the terminal on a flight-by-flight basis.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo True, although I myself have never been bussed at MUC, always walked up the jetway. And I live in ZRH so have been to MUC a fair deal.

Comment: Even for the planes parking directly at the terminal, there are no distinct parking positions for different kinds of arrivals. In Terminal 1, you usually have to pass the immigration booths no matter where you are coming from, the checkpoints are either staffed or simply open, depending on where the flight is coming from. In Terminal 2, the Schengen area is on the lower floor and the Non-Schengen area on the upper floor directly above. Coming out of the jetway, you are simply led to the correct floor depending on the origin of the flight.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Ah, didn't know about T1 (when arriving there I usually head for departures and have a meal at the restaurant, then clear immigration at the small special exit.)